# ColorBox not loading - all JS is pulling through correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I've tried to set up a colorbox (when you click on the 'sign me up' button) but it doesn't seem to launch. Can't find any javascript errors or console errors, just doesn't seem to fire.

I've linked the stylesheet, JS file and included the header script, they all open up fine and are being correctly called into the page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
        $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
        $(".callbacks").colorbox({
          onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
          onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
          onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
          onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
          onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
        });

        //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
        $("#click").click(function(){ 
          $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

I've created the inline content div (hidden) and linked the button correctly.

```
<span class="btn"><a href="#inline_content">Sign Me Up!</a></span>
```

And here is the inline content:

```
<div style='display:none'>
  <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
  <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
  <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live site demo](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All selectors in your code are broken. Try this code:

```
<span class="btn"><a class="callbacks" href="#inline_content">Sign Me Up!</a></span>
```

And jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".callbacks").colorbox({
      inline:true,
      onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
      onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
      onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
      onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
      onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a4urV/

Comment: I've changed my site to the code you gave me, but it is still not working. The code was taken from the colorbox example so I think it was correct and there must be a broken link somewhere else along the line? You can view updated version here again:http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/

Comment: Francesca, it looks like you have invalid jQuery. There are far too many closing brackets. Please look above as I've updated my answer to make it easier for you. Remove all the code between <script> and </script> and place the snippet I've provided for you there instead and add class="inline" to the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the .inline class on the link that you want to open the colorbox.

```
<span class="btn"><a href="#inline_content" class="inline">Sign Me Up!</a></span>
```

That will utilize this colorbox instantiation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
});
```

You don't need to have all of those callbacks to load colorbox, so I recommend using this colorbox instantiation (.inline) rather than the .callbacks one.

- Chris

**EDIT:**

As of this moment your jQuery is invalid, causing it to break:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".callbacks").colorbox({
      inline:true,
      onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
      onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
      onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
      onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
      onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });
}); <-- Extra closing tag
        }); <-- Extra closing tag

        //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
        $("#click").click(function(){ 
          $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

I recommend for the sake of simplicity and to fix your errors, to replace that entire code with the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
    });
</script>
```

and then add class="inline" to your link, and it will work like a charm =]